# My alarm app won't display alarm notification or play alarm sound?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm using AlarmManager to make an alarm. I'm not sure why it's not working feel free to ask for more code. Thank you in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        int y = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int mon = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int d = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                        if (ampm.equals("pm")){
                            h=h+12;
                        }
                        calendar.set(y, mon, d, h, m);
                        alarmIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * intervalMinute, alarmIntent);
                    } else {
                        if (alarmMgr!=null) {
                            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
                        }
                    }
```

There are no errors.

Comment: Does `AlarmReceiver` registered in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and enabled  ?

Comment: Yes it is in my manifest and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

`setRepeating` is equivalent to `setInexactRepeating` on API levels 19+. From the documentation:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

You would need to call `set`, `setExact` or (maybe) `setAlarmInfo` based on your target API level, and schedule repeat alarms manually.

Also, double check your logic for setting the time for your next alarm, as right now it looks overcomplicated to me. You can just do:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(1, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); //Just an example
alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

I've posted an Alarm app on GitHub that may be of use to as well ([link](https://github.com/PPartisan/Simple-Alarms/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/ppartisan/simplealarms/service/AlarmReceiver.java)).